# How to change the heading of the filter section in change list page of Django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django and I want to change the  heading of the filter section which is marked in the pic:

[image]

And my admin file looks like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So can we change the heading of the filter section without changing any thing else??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this first add this line to your admin file :

```
change_list_template='change_list_form.html'
```

So your admin.py file is :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_list_template='change_list_form.html'

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that create a file in the templates folder with name : `change_list_form.html` and add the following code to that file :

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}

{% block filters %}
{% if cl.has_filters %}


<h2>Write here your new heading</h2>


{% if cl.preserved_filters %}<h3 id="changelist-filter-clear">
<a href="?{% if cl.is_popup %}_popup=1{% endif %}">&#10006; {% trans "Clear all filters" %}</a>
</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}{% admin_list_filter cl spec %}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I hope it help you.